# Dynamic tabs or dropdown list for the same view but different data

Tags: android, tabs, spinner

I have the following scenario and I'm not sure what is the best UX

I'm working on an android app where the user is a parent and they are viewing some data for their children (i.e. it's the same view with the same components but with different data for each child)

Question: What is the easiest way to let parents choose between their children?

Someone suggested **tabs** where each child has his/her own tab, but I found this a bad UX, as we're displaying the same view on different tabs, (I guess tabs is better for different view, right ?)

another suggestion was using **spinner**/dropdown list

The final one is to have a **different view** with the children list, and when the user chooses a child it redirects to the main view (this has a drawback if the parent switches a lot between the children they'll be going back and forth a lot)

Is one of these the preferred method or is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT**
here is a screenshot for an initial (uncomplete) prototype with tabs

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible to include a screenshot of current implementation?

Comment: Perhaps use a spinner with images. I think that might be the kind of personal touch a parent might appreciate.

Comment: @Dipak edited the question with a sceenshot for an initial prototype

Comment: If you are showing events and other details - in that case tabs are the most preferable choice. Check photos section of facebook's mobile app - they have used tabs for the same behaviour.

Comment: @dr.innoWave, whats the objective of the view? Do you want to see a month worth of activity or 1 week or just for current day? Do you want to see when schedules overlap on which day, what if the even is at different times?

Answer (score 1):

The tabs are a problem if there ar more then three or for children or when they have long names.

What if the parents want to now all the data of all children. In this case they ought to have the possibility to select more then one child.

So my sugestion is not to have tabs but to have a checkboxlist like a menu.[image]

Comment: I think it's a great idea, but how would you mark days when e.g. 4 children have an event that same day?

Comment: I tried to show that in the Mockup. On the 12/2. Ther are two children with an event. But i didn't put much thought in it, beacous this was not the question....

Answer (score 0):

A little bit rough mockup, but I'll try to explain... you basically have one window, with a search/tag input you can search as many students as you want and each student you find has a unique colour, the calendar shows all students events according to their colours.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmFKHT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>